# I'm in lips or in hair

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry, limerick

> Sometimes I like to be part of the game;
>   Sometimes I'm part of an exercise name.
>   I'm in lips or in hair;
>   I'm afield so beware;
>   I'm in many a place but direct is never my aim.

What am I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This looks like a

> curl

Sometimes I like to be part of the game;

> curling - a sport where players slide  granite stones down a sheet of ice

Sometimes I'm part of an exercise name.

> arm or leg curls against resistance

I'm in lips or in hair;

> curl one's lips and hair ringlets

I'm afield so beware;

> beware of a curve ball, caused by spin on an object as in baseball or cricket

I'm in many a place but direct is never my aim.

> curl - a curved shape as is common in nature and design

Comment: In that case, I'm disappointed that the puzzle didn't include a line referring to vector calculus :-)

Comment: Tom, that's it, great job again!! My intent for line 4 will probably satisfy @Rand al'Thor, though: the math curl is "afield" - a vector field, that is. :)

Comment: After reading about the curl more I think my interpretation is wrong. A curl is not a vector field, only an operator on a vector field. My attempt to be cute failed, oops